# MySQL query show something like 0x8081 instead of special characters

Tags: mysql, database-design, character-set, utf-8

When i run `SELECT CHAR(128,129,130,131,132,133,134,135,136,137);`

I got `0x80818283848586878889` istead of `Çüéâäàåçêë`.

Does anybody know why?, I'm using charset `utf8mb4`.

When I run `show variables like '%char%';` I got

[image]

I'm using  MySQL version 8.0.26

---

The output charset is "DOS West European"

```
SELECT CHAR(128,129,130,131,132,133,134,135,136,137 using cp850)
```

Which is really weird. I got this query from *"Learning SQL"* book by O'Reilly and they said this charset is `utf8mb4`

Answer (score 1):

`80818283848586878889` is `Çüéâäàåçêë` in CHARACTER SET cp850, not utf8mb4.

If your *client* has hex 80, 81, etc (decimal 128,129, etc), then tell MySQL that by doing

- (Preferably) When connecting, say that the charset is `cp850`.
- (or, if necessary) Issuing `SET NAMES cp850` right after connecting.

That way, the client can continue with cp850, while the data is stored as utf8mb4, which happens to be hex `C387 C3BC C3A9 C3A2 C3A4 C3A0 C3A5 C3A7 C3AA C3AB`.  (I added spaces for clarity.)

I've never seen or used the syntax you got from that antique book.  I deduce that it is saying "treat 80,81, etc as CP850 and convert it to the character set you are using".  Note:

```
SELECT CHAR(0xC387C3A7 USING utf8mb4);
+--------------------------------+
| CHAR(0xC387C3A7 USING utf8mb4) |
+--------------------------------+
| Çç                             |
+--------------------------------+
```

Notice how that converted it "correctly" when the hex and charset match.

Perhaps `CHAR(... USING ...)` is a synonym for `CONVERT(... USING ...)`.